# How can i show data to my table using vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Hi am trying to put this script on my file.

```
<template>
  <b-table striped hover :items="items"></b-table>
</template>
<script>
const items = [
  { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
  { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
  { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
  { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
]

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      items: items
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

in my file i take the data not from const items like the example but i use this script:

```
computed: {
    siteObject() {
      console.log(this.site);
      return this.site;
    },
```

how can put this info in my table ?

i use this to show my data:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in siteObject.cases" :key="index" >
```

Comment: where do you get the `site` property?

Comment: I am starting learning with  this you mean this  props: ["site"] ?

Comment: ah ok a this variable comes from props, and you want to show its items in the table?

Comment: yes exactely please

Comment: done  merci ... !